# не получается найти элемент в selenium

Tags: html, selenium

Вообщем нужно выполнить некоторые действия на сайте ea.com, но при заходе появляется окошко с куками, а нажать на кнопку принять у меня почему-то не получается.

```html
<a class="acceptAllButtonLower" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-hidden="false" style="">Accept All</a>
```

```
                try:
                    el = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'acceptAllButtonLower')
                except Exception as ex:
                    try:
                        el = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[text()='Accept All']")
                    except Exception as ex:
                        try:
                            el = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".acceptAllButtonLower")
                        except Exception as ex:
                            print("не нашов")
```

в логе надпись не нашов)

Comment: Было бы информативные для вас выводить ошибки, читать и делать выводы, ошибку "не нашов" сложнее гуглить, не так ли? XPATH полный нужно вставлять, про остальные случаи: скорее всего элементов с таким классом не 1 штука, следовательно возникает неприятность, программа не понимает какой именно элемент нужен.

Comment: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[text()='Decline All']"}

Comment: Ну вот вам и написано в чем дело.  Что бы найти по XPATH, как написал ранее, нужно указывать полный маршрут. "Копировать полную строку XPATH"

Comment: скопировал xpath с кода, но Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[8]/div[1]/div/div[7]/a[2]"}

Comment: Таймслипы ставили? `time.sleep(3)`

Comment: конечно. я почитал ещё в интернете, вроде как это окошко с куки считается iframe и искать нужно видимо по другому

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Документация](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/interactions/frames/)

Из документации следует: при работе с iframe, нужно переключиться на нужный iframe, в нем кликнуть на нужный элемент.

```
# хранение iframe
iframe = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#modal > iframe")

# переключаемся на нужный iframe
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)

# кликаем на кнопку
driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'button').click()

# выход из iframe 
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

На основе этого примера можете отредактировать свой код. Больше примеров и описания всех функций так же доступно в документации.